# Trying low bar position is difficult, what can I do to get there?

Tags: weightlifting, form

I'm trying to get to where I can squat with the bar in the low bar position as in [Mark's video](http://startingstrength.com/index.php/site/video/platform_the_squat_bar_position).

I'm having difficulties getting into this position and I think it's a mix of things, one being inflexibility in my shoulders. What can I do to help me be able to get into the proper position for lower back squats?

To expand on what my issue is, I'm somewhat able to get into the position, but my wrists end up way past the bar and end up wrapping over it instead of wresting on top of the bar. Trying to squat in this position doesn't feel stable, even with trying to keep my elbows back. I tried widening the placement of my wrists, but that relaxed my back too much and made the bar shift a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I used to have exactly that problem, with shoulder inflexibility. I got myself a [Thera Cane](http://www.theracane.com/) and followed the instructions in Clair Davies' [Trigger Point Therapy Workbook](http://www.triggerpointbook.com/), within a couple weeks I could usually get my hands to the right position on a bar, although it took a couple months to be able to consistently do it.